# CSS: Why is vertical-align: baseline stop working on Firefox when using overflow: hidden?

Tags: css, overflow, vertical-alignment

You can reproduce this by running this [test case](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20101129-vertical-align-baseline-overflow-hidden.html). The results are shown in the screenshot below. The issue is that on Firefox, when adding a `overflow: hidden` on the "block" (with grey background in the screenshot), the block stop being aligned as I'd like it to be: instead of the baseline of the text in the block being align to the the baseline of the parent box, it is as if the bottom of the block was aligned on the baseline of the parent box. As you can see in the screenshot, this doesn't happen with Chrome.

1. Is this a Firefox bug?
2. How to get the expected result on Firefox (baseline alignment with `overflow: hidden`)?

[image: Screenshot]

Note: Using `vertical-align: middle` on "block" doesn't cut it, as what I really want is baseline alignment. You can see more clearly that `vertical-align: middle` doesn't do baseline alignment by setting `padding: 1em 0 .1em 0` (more padding at the top of the box), which give you:

[image: With vertical-align: middle]

Comment: try text-bottom for your vertical alignment, that works with the extra padding

Comment: Sebastian, `vertical-align: text-bottom` doesn't work; again this is very different from baseline alignment. You can see it ver clearly by putting `padding: .3em 0 1em 0; vertical-align: text-bottom`.

Comment: It seems that this might be a legit bug. It doesn't seem to be caused by the Firefox default spreadsheet; I've injected numerous different browser default spreadsheets into Firefox, and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @yc: agree. @Alessandro: if you set a large bottom padding, it will look off center in any browser, for example, see this in chrome or ie: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/vKjyZ/1/

Comment: @yc, I am also tempted to think this is a Firefox bug, and was going to file a bug about this one. The thing that made me reconsider is that Opera 10 behave like Firefox, not like Chrome/Safari. So could it be a Firefox and Opera bug?

Comment: @Sebastian, this is because you have a `vertical-align:text-bottom`. Remove it, and it will look fine in Chrome. See: http://jsfiddle.net/axrmH/

Comment: IE10 (and IE9, I think) behaves the same as Firefox. This is incredibly annoying!

Answer (score 13):

It does look like overflow:hidden is buggy in that it removes the baseline from an inline-block element. Fortunately, there's a seemingly redundant Mozilla CSS extension value for overflow that prevents overflow but doesn't exhibit this buggy behaviour.

Try this:

```
.block {
    width: 10em; padding: .3em 0 .1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #666; background-color: #eee;    
}
```

It looks like it corrects the problem in Firefox and doesn't mess with Safari.

**Update:**

It looks like Firefox and Opera are rendering overflow:hidden inline blocks correctly and Webkit browsers are not.

According to the [W3C CSS2 Working Draft's Visual Formatting Model Details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align),

> *The baseline of an 'inline-block' is
>   the baseline of its last line box in
>   the normal flow, unless it has either
>   no in-flow line boxes or if its
>   'overflow' property has a computed
>   value other than 'visible', in which
>   case the baseline is the bottom margin
>   edge.*

Comment: At first glance, this part of the standard seems really stupid. But I know there are usually good reasons for the standard being the way it is. Does anyone know why the behaviour described in the standard would be the desired one?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `vertical-align: text-bottom;` to `.block`

you can also try to set equal line-heights for `.label` and `.block`

Comment: Sebastian, good idea, but `vertical-align: middle` is not baseline alignment, and won't give you the right alignment, except in some very particular situation—as a broken clock gives you the right time twice a day ;). I also added a note to my question about this, with a screenshot.

Comment: @alessandro: saw that, edited the answer: maybe `vertical-align: text-bottom;`?

Comment: Same thing: see my comment to your comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.label {
        float: left;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        }
```

this will get the desired result in both FF and Chrome/Safari.  Did not test in IE however.

Comment: you are adjusting the `line-height` of the label in pixels until it looks OK. In my book, this is not a solution in the HTML/CSS world (it would be in Photoshop). With this solution, decrease the font size and the label is too high; increase it and it is too low. Also if the `padding` for "block" changes, you'll have to adjust the number of pixels.