# Weird CSS result in Firefox compared to expected result in chrome (some divs are not aligned but shifted down)

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

With this HTML markup :

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="tag-list">
        <li class="tag"><div class="tag-label">short tag</div><div class="tag-tail tag-count">1154353</div></li><!--no whitespaces between list items!!--><li class="tag"><div class="tag-label">A quite long long long long long tag</div><div class="tag-tail tag-active">5</div></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And this CSS rules :

```
.tag-list {
    border:1px solid red;
}

.tag {
    border:1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;/*so that tags are lined up like words... */
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    white-space:nowrap; /* so that label & tail sub-divs are stuck all together */
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em; /* text is vertically centered */
}

.tag > div {
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block; /*so that label&tail are lined up */    
}

.tag-tail {
    border:1px solid orange;
}

.tag-label {
    border:1px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    max-width:10em; /* to generate a (text) overflow for the ellipsis*/
}
```

I get the expected result in Chrome 22.0.1229.94

But in Firefox 15.0.1, i get a weird result (`div.tag-tail` elements are shifted down) !

You can compare the results in FF and Chrome with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tr5ea/1/).

I know that adding the property `overflow:hidden;` to the selector/rule `.tag-tail` fixes the issue, but i'd like to understand why this is needed for FF and why there is this difference in behaviors ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: It seems that this issue has already been commented several times : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310047/css-why-is-vertical-align-baseline-stop-working-on-firefox-when-using-overflow), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930598/text-in-div-element-is-raised-above-horizontally-aligned-span-element-in-firefox) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789854/overflow-hidden-causing-alignment-issues-in-firefox)... Adding `vertical-align:top;` property to all my divs fixes my issue

Comment: Tough i'd like to know which browser implementation is right : Chrome webkit or Firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS spec says at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#leading last paragraph:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

So in your case, the `.tag-label` has its baseline at the bottom of its margin edge (and since it has no margins, that means at the bottom edge of its bottom border.  But the `.tag-tail` has its baseline on the baseline of the text inside it.  And since everything here is baseline-aligned, that means that the baseline of the text in the `.tag-tail` needs to end up on the same vertical position as the bottom of the border for the `.tag-label`.

Which is exactly what Firefox does.  Chrome doesn't implement the spec for baselines of inline blocks correctly; see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36084

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:hidden;` seems like a strange thing to add.

I would do what **loic** suggested in the comments:

Add vertical align.
I was going through a similar issue earlier, `vertical-align:top;` was my solution as well.
(By the way, Firefox 16 will also display undesirable results.)

```
.tag > div {  
     height: 100%;  
    display:inline-block;   
    vertical-align:top;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had too much stuff going on in .tag-label

Here is your solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrbinky3000/JU5Cr/

```
.tag-label {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

But this is a better solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrbinky3000/gwb7d/1/

```
.tag-list {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}

.tag {
    border:1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;/*so that tags are lined up like words... */
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    white-space:nowrap; /* so that label & tail sub-divs are stuck all together */
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em; /* text is vertically centered */
    overflow: hidden;

}

.tag > div {
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    float: left;        
}

.tag-tail {
    border:1px solid orange;
}

.tag-label {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

If you float a div, it comes out of the "page flow" and the div shrinks to fit the contents, very similarly to what happens when you set something to "inline-block".  However, unlike inline-block, you don't have to worry about whitespace in the code messing things up.   Display block ignores leading and trailing whitespace.